# Find point horizontal degree on rotated ellipse tangent to bounding box

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Here is the image:

[image]

I've calculated bounding box coordinates as in below formula

[image]
[image]

the rotated ellipse formula is:

[image]

I just want to know the angle of the point degree from horizontal line, like the first image shows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One could simply solve the equations $dy/dx=0$ or $dx/dy=0$, but a geometric approach is much more fun.

Vertical semidiameter $OH$ is conjugated to semidiameter $OG$ (see figure below), hence:
$$
ab=2\,\text{area}(\triangle OGH)=OH\cdot OM,
$$
that is:
$$
OH={ab\over OM}={2ab\over w},
$$
where $w=AB$ is the width of the bounding box.
On the other hand, we also have
$$
OH^2+OG^2=a^2+b^2, 
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
OG^2=a^2+b^2-{4a^2b^2\over w^2}. 
$$
It follows that
$$
\cos\alpha={OM\over OG}={w\over 2OG}=
{w\over 2\sqrt{a^2+b^2-{4a^2b^2/ w^2}}}.
$$
With an analogous calculation you can find $\cos\beta$ (just substitute $w$ with the height of the bounding box).

EDIT.

Substituting here your formula for $w$ and using some trig identities, one can find a reasonably simple formula for $\tan\alpha$:

$$
\tan\alpha=\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right) \sin \theta\cos \theta}
{a^2 \cos ^2 \theta+b^2 \sin ^2 \theta}.
$$
This is just to compare with the result in the other answer, which is different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the formula.

In the rotated ellipse coordinate system, below degree defines from the rotated x axis. see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU7cN.png)

x axis points degree
$$
- \arctan \left ( \frac{b^{2} * \sin \theta }{a ^{2} * \cos\theta } \right )   
$$

y axis points degree
$$
- \arctan \left ( - \frac{b^{2} * \cos \theta }{a ^{2} *\sin \theta } \right )   
$$

In rectangular coordinate system, these degree should plus the $ \theta $. which should be the truly answer of this question.

x axis points degree
$$
\theta - \arctan \left ( \frac{b ^{2}  *\sin \theta }{a ^{2} *\cos\theta } \right )   
$$

y axis points degree
$$
\theta - \arctan \left ( - \frac{b ^{2}  *\cos \theta }{a ^{2} *\sin \theta } \right )   
$$

$ \theta $ means the ellipse rotate degree from rectangular coordinate system x axis.

I was inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433347/how-to-get-axis-aligned-bounding-box-of-an-ellipse-with-all-given-parameters)
the function `extrema`  call codes, which the y axis condition needs the loop. then I changed it to the above formula.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong: it is not true that $a=b$ when $\theta=45°$, sorry. But I checked your formulas with GeoGebra and they don't work.

Comment: I had confused $a$ and $b$ with the sides of the bounding box, which in fact are equal when $\theta=45°$. But I constructed the ellipse with GeoGebra and can confirm that the formulas in your answer don't work, while my formulas are correct. I'd suggest you to verify that by yourself.

Comment: last comment need condition $ a= 100, b=50 $, and the my formula result 79.0569 equals the result here https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoqiL.png

Comment: For $a=2b$ my formula gives $\alpha=\beta\approx30.96376°$, which is indeed the correct value, as you can see [in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEu5y.png).

Comment: Let me arbitrate between you two. The formula derived by @Intelligentipauca is correct. The correct value of $\alpha$ of the considered case $a=2b=100$ is $30.96375653207352141710767984083^o$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca sorry, my mistake at all, fixed now. I was confused with the ellipse theta. Previous answer should be polar angle of the point.

Comment: @YNK sorry, my mistake at all, fixed now. I was confused with the ellipse theta. Previous answer should be polar angle of the point.